# Unable to Create a Primary Key Foreign Key Relationship with Composite Primary Key in TypeORM

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, typeorm, composite-primary-key

I'm facing an issue while trying to create a foreign key relationship in TypeORM where the foreign key references a composite primary key. I expect the foreign key to also act as a primary key in the table where it is defined, but instead, I receive a "DataTypeNotSupportedError" when attempting to implement this.

Steps to reproduce

```
@Entity()
export class FirstEntity {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  primaryKey1: string;

  @PrimaryColumn()
  primaryKey2: string;
}

@Entity()
export class SecondEntity {
    @PrimaryColumn()
    column1: string;

    @PrimaryColumn()
    @ManyToOne(() => FirstEntity)
    @JoinColumn([
        { name: 'primaryKey1', referencedColumnName: 'primaryKey1' },
        { name: 'primaryKey2', referencedColumnName: 'primaryKey2' },
    ])
    firstEntity: FirstEntity;
}
```

Environment:

```
Node.js version: v18.13.0
TypeScript version: 4.7.4
TypeORM version: 0.3.16
Operating System: Windows 11
```

**Expected Behavior**:
I expect to be able to define a foreign key in TypeORM that references a composite primary key and also acts as a primary key in the table where it is defined.

Actual Behavior:
Instead of being able to define the foreign key as a primary key, I encounter a "DataTypeNotSupportedError" when trying to implement this relationship.

Please note that I have already checked the dependencies, devDependencies, and versions mentioned above, and they appear to be correctly installed in my environment.

I tried creating a foreign key to a table with a primary key. I wanted my foreign key also to be part of a primary. TypeORM throws DataTypeNotSupportedError.